# Avast deleted my server.php file now I have uninstalled avast pasted server.php file in the root of directory still website doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, visual-studio-code, server

Whenever I started php artisan serve it deleted serever.php file. Now I have uninstalled avast antivirus but still it gives this error and does not open the site properly.
PS C:\xampp\htdocs\ecom_proj> php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: http://127.0.0.1:8000

```
**[Fri Dec 11 12:52:23 2020] PHP 7.4.5 Development Server (http://127.0.0.1:8000) started
    [Fri Dec 11 12:52:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:54908 Accepted
    [Fri Dec 11 12:52:45 2020] 127.0.0.1:54909 Accepted
    [Fri Dec 11 12:52:51 2020] 127.0.0.1:54908 Closing**
```

Comment: Are you saying your "anti-virus" corrupted your dev environment and that you do not have a working backup? ........ If so, backup now, reinstalll your dev stuff, and then overwrite the sources from your backup. (Uninstall Avast too)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the example shown only shows communication with a browser. Closing the connection is normal behavior. (Note the port. Your server is running on port 8000).

2. You should check the antivirus logs what has been removed. It doesn't necessarily have to be just `server.php`. For example: Eset deleted the file where it found:

```php
//<script src="http://link-to-site-detected-as-abusive">
```

3. Have you restored the `server.php` file in the correct version of Laravel?
4. Maybe you have a bug in your code.

Comment: [Wed Dec 16 12:48:01 2020] 127.0.0.1:52274 Closed without sending a request; it was probably just an unused speculative preconnection

Comment: This page isn’t working127.0.0.1 is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500

Answer (score 0):

### I have already faced this problem.

This error happens because the "server.php" file is missing.
Antiviruses and Avast antivirus either deleted or removed it from your project directory into Virus chest.

### You can recover from the antivirus chest and create an exemption for that file.

### If the antivirus is uninstalled, the solution however is you can copy "server.php" file from any other laravel project directory and paste it into the root directory of your laravel project

Alternatively, you can create a "server.php" file at the root of your project.
after creating the file, paste the following code into the "server.php" file you created:

```
<?PHP
/**
* Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
*
* @package  Laravel
* @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
*/
$uri = urldecode(
parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH)
);
// This file allows us to emulate Apache's "mod_rewrite" functionality from the
// built-in PHP web server. This provides a convenient way to test a Laravel
// application without having installed a "real" web server software here.
if ($uri !== '/' && file_exists(__DIR__.'/public'.$uri)) {
return false;
}

require_once __DIR__.'/public/index.php';
```